# Class derived from QwtPlotZoomer not working as intended

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwt

I am writing a class `MyPlotZoomer` that derives from `QwtPlotZoomer`. `MyPlotZoomer` differs from `QwtPlotZoomer` in that in order to activate and draw the zoom rectangle, the user has to press and hold the ctrl key, click and drag, and then release mouse button.

To achieve this, I overrode three methods from `QWtPlotZoomer`, `widgetMouseReleaseEvent`, `widgetMousePressEvent` and `widgetMouseMoveEvent` in the following way：

```
#include <QWidget>
#include "qwt_plot.h"
#include "qwt_plot_zoomer.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MyPlotZoomer : public QwtPlotZoomer
{

  public:
    // constructor
        explicit MyPlotZoomer( QWidget *canvas );
    // destructor

    // function prototypes

    // data
  protected:
    // function prototypes
    virtual void widgetMouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent *mouse_event ) override{
        if( mouse_event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ){
          QwtPlotZoomer::widgetMouseReleaseEvent( mouse_event );
        }
    };

    virtual void widgetMousePressEvent( QMouseEvent *mouse_event ) override{
        if( mouse_event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ){
          QwtPlotZoomer::widgetMousePressEvent( mouse_event );
        }
    };
    virtual void widgetMouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *mouse_event ) override{
        if( mouse_event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ){
          QwtZoomer::widgetMouseMoveEvent( mouse_event );
        }
    };


};
```

However, pressing ctrl key and then drawing does nothing. The zoom rectangle doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's seems to me you forget Q_OBJECT, btw

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, presence of `Q_OBJECT` is not required if signals/slots aren't involved.

Comment: @vahancho I know I just point on it among other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the base classes of QwtPlotZoomer is QwtEventPattern, that allows to change what type of key/mouse combinations are used.
So there is no reason for deriving from QwtPlotZoomer as setKeyPattern/setMousePattern does it in a much simpler way.

The Mouse/Key patterns being used depend on the state machine ( QwtPickerMachine ) being assigned to your zoomer. Check the corresponding class documentation.

Comment: After reading your answer, I solved my problem using QwtPlotZoomer::setMousePattern( QwtEventPattern::MouseSelect1, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::ControlModifier ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
if( mouse_event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ){
```

with

```
if( mouse_event->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) ){
```

or

```
if( mouse_event->modifiers() | Qt::ControlModifier ){
```

and in other places too

**Addition.**
To zoom in/out you need  to call QwtPlotZoomer::zoom() on the release event. On the press event to start to create rectangle, on the move - modify the rectangle respectively and on the release to call zoom with that rectangle as an argument

Comment: @megamonium can you check out the modifiers' content?

Comment: So I add this line "std::cout << mouse_event->modifiers() << std::endl;" to the very beginning of the body of widgetMouseReleaseEvent（ QMouseEvent *mouse_event  ). Without pressing ctrl, the value returned by modifiers() is 0. With ctrl pressed, the value returned is 67108864. I added Q_OBJECT and tried again but still no luck...

Comment: That is right (Control is pressed). Try to out: std::cout << mouse_event->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier)

Comment: The value returned is 1.

Comment: So it means "True" and your code must do its work. May be you need to call **QwtPlotZoomer::zoom()** method? )

Comment: I think the QwtPlotZoomer::zoom() method is called in the QwtPlotZoomer::widgetMouseReleaseEvent() method, which is already called in the body of MyPlotZoomer::widgetMouseReleaseEvent() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185605/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-megamonium).

Comment: I actually need to get going now, maybe we can continue this another day? Thanks so much for answering my post : )

Comment: I'm in the chat )